# Remotely Launch an application on a remote machine with C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, opc

Please,

i desperately need help. I am trying to figure out how to send TCP Data Packets (C#) to an OPC Server in order to be able to control and monitor my linear motor?  A simple solution could be to launch the application (exe.file) of the OPC Server on a remote computer...
But i have no clue how to launch an application remotely with C#. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? What have you tried so far? Do you have any code at all, you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

I consider you have an OPC DA Server.

OPC DA Server is a DCOM server application. DCOM servers start automatically, when a client tries to access it, if you have configured the DCOM access rights properly. That said, DCOM is quite difficult to configure and you may expose your computer to security risks by doing so.

An option is to use applications like [UaGateway](http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-gateway.php) that can tunnel the traffic via another protocol. The UaGateway converts the traffic to OPC UA in between. You must install one of such applications to both ends.

Comment: Thank you very much... So i should install Uagateway on both the two machines. Now how should the C# programm look like? Please can u help me in that direction?

Comment: You need to write an OPC client application. If you have the UaGateway, you can develop an OPC UA Client application, for example with the .NET SDK, http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-dotNET-sdk.php

Comment: Now i get it. I need to write an OPC Client-Application (in C#) to call my OPC Server on a remote machine. I would lie to enable the communication via Tcp-Datapackets. Can you give me some tipps? ;) Thank you!

Comment: I still have one question. I already have an OPC-Client which can be connected to the OPC-Server on a windows machine. Please can u tell me how i can realize a remote procedure call (with C#) to start my oPC-server? Thanks

Comment: The server will start automatically, when you access it from the client, if you have the appropriate DCOM permissions enabled.